# Does Javascript / jQuery have system vars?

Tags: javascript, jquery, system-variable

I noticed strange issue.

Look at this jQuery:

```
$(function(){
    status = 1;
    status1 = 2;

    $('body').append(status+' - '+status1);
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/narekmarkosyan/4JrBK/4/)

As you can see output is:

```
- 2
```

So `status` is system var for JavaScript or jQuery?

And is there any other vars like this?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window

Comment: :).. the output is `1-2` in chrome....

Comment: i see '1-2' in the fiddle

Comment: There are reserved words although `status` does NOT belong to them: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words - Global object window does have a `status` property though (don't know if this is true for all browsers) so you shouldn't use a global var named like that: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.status

Comment: Which browser does not show the `1`?

Comment: Ahh I checked in Chrome and it show `1 - 2`...

Comment: It works fine in Firefox and Chrome. I also tried IE and it will work if you define the variables using "var status = 1"

Comment: @balafi: Because in this case `status` is a *local* variable.

Comment: What on earth are you talking about?!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

JavaScript has *global* variables and in browsers, global variables are properties of the [*global object*](http://es5.github.io/#x15.1) which is `window`.

Now, `window` itself has a couple of predefined properties and **some of them are read-only**, like [`window.status` *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.status) (this can also differ from browser to browser!). Creating a global variable with such a name will therefore fail (the variable already exists, but you cannot assign a new value to it).

You can find a list of predefined properties in the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window).

---

This one of the reasons why you should **avoid** global variables. If you use local variables (by declaring variables with `var` and if necessary, put all your code in a function), you don't have this problem:

```
(function() {
    var status = 'foo';
    // ....
}());
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. But not all of this vars is readonly, right? I changed it to `statusbar` and it returns `1 - 2` http://jsfiddle.net/narekmarkosyan/4JrBK/5/

Comment: An is it possible to get list of all that vars to avoid of them (in case I forgot to make them local)?

Comment: Quoting myself again: *"You can find a list of predefined properties in the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window)"*.

Comment: Well, as I said, that differs from browser to browser. You should avoid overwriting any of them anyways.

Answer (score 3):

The global object `window` does have a property called `status` used for setting the text in the status bar at the bottom of the browser.

By not using the `var` keyword you are overwriting this property as you refer to `window.status`. Apparently Firefox won't let you change this though as long as the user hasn't set the `dom.disable_window_status_change` preference to `false`.

See **[this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.status)** for documentation and **[this one](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window)** for a list of all "global" properties.

Also there are some words in JS that are considered reserved, so you should avoid **[using these](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words)**, even in local scopes.

Comment: Thanks, that list of Reserved Words is necessary to know too. They almost always they highlighted by IDE, that really help, instead of var from question. Right highlight will prevent this question.

Comment: Using reserved keywords out of context will throw a syntax error  most of the time anyway.