# Creating an element ID "on the fly" doesn't work in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following HTML structure:

```
<div class='message_top' id='top_7' style='cursor:pointer;'>
    <div class='top_ime'>From: official</div>
    <div class='top_status' id='status_7'>
        <img src='images/message_new.png' height='26' title='New message' />
    </div>
</div>
```

In addition to this, there are a lot of other DIVs of the same structure, but with different ID numbers, for example:

```
<div class='message_top' id='top_15' style='cursor:pointer;'>
    <div class='top_ime'>From: official</div>
    <div class='top_status' id='status_15'>
        <img src='images/message_new.png' height='26' title='New message' />
    </div>
</div>
```

Now, I have a jQuery function which takes the ID of a `.message_top` div and it should perform an action using the contents of the `.top_status` div which belongs to it. However, for some reason, in the syntax it doesn't seem to recognize the ID of the `.top_status` div. I know I'm nto explaining this very well, but here's a fiddle that will help your understand (code and commentary are there):

http://jsfiddle.net/gMy2f/1/

```
$(function () {
    $('.message_top').click(function(){
        var id = this.id;
        status_id = id.replace("top","status");
        status = $("#"+status_id).html();
        alert(status_id+" "+status);    //status variable is empty, but...
        status2 = $("#status_7").html();
        alert(status2);                 //status2 has the expected value
    });
});
```

So, as you see, if I call the `.html()` method using `$("#status_7").html();` it works fine, but if I call it with `$("#"+status_id).html();` (with status_id being "status_7") it doesn't work. What's happening here? I've used similar code a bunch of times and never had any issues.

Comment: Seems to work fine if you load you code in the proper place (hint: on doc ready or load). http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/gMy2f/4/

Comment: @j08691 I just tried your code, and it fails the same way mine does (in Firefox at least) - and I'm pretty sure my way of loading it is fine.

Comment: The code is working just fine in firefox 19.0.2, Maybe a browser compatibilty issue?

Comment: @gbtimmon I think this way of creating IDs is pretty standard, surely it can't be browser-specific? Besides, I'm using firefox too.

Comment: You're correct, the loading was fine, however the code also works fine, in Chrome at least.

Comment: I dont know what to tell you then it work for me without issue... I was thinking maybe the `id.replace("top","status");` might have compatibily issue. Doubtful but thats the best i can come up with.

Comment: Bad things happen when you forget `var`!!

Comment: Yeah @Pointy - adding var fixed it. I know why I forgot it too - I cut this bit of code out of an old piece of code which had the variables initialized beforehand!

Comment: @gbtimmon Declaring everything as a local var solved it. Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use **local** variables instead of global ones. `window.status` is predefined and potential read only.

I just answered this today: [Does Javascript / jQuery have system vars?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15946978/does-javascript-jquery-have-system-vars/15947073#15947073)

[**Updated jsFiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/gMy2f/8/)

Comment: Indeed. Simply adding `var` in front of the variable definition fixed the issue. Thanks.

Comment: @jovan This might explain why it works in the jsfiddle but not in your browser. I belive, but could be wrong, that the jsfiddle places all of the javascripts vars in a container object to separate the user code from the page code, even when they are declared globally.

Comment: @gbtimmon: Mmh. I don't think so. The fiddle didn't work for me in Firefox (in Firefox `window.status` is read-only by default). jsFiddle executes the code in an iframe, but that should have any impact on this.

Comment: My firefox is different then your then...After checking, I was able to edit window.status from the console. Weird....

Comment: @gbtimmon: Could be, you can make `window.status` writable: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.status.